# How to pass data toTaggableManager django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my Django model have `TaggableManager` field, I want to store data in database, in which format I need to pass data to TaggableManager field.

```
tags=TaggableManager(through=Tags)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the [*documentation*](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) says, you can add tags like:

```
some_instance.tags.add(tag1, tag2, tag3)
```

Since you use a custom `Tags` model, these tags (`tag1`, `tag2`, etc.) are instances of the `Tags` model.

You can use the API as well to

1. `.remove(tag2, tag3)`: remove `tag2` and `tag3` from the instance;
2. `.clear(..)`: remove all the tags;
3. `.set(tag1, tag3)` change the tags to `tag1` and `tag3` (equivalent to `.clear(..)` and `.add(..)`);

and other functions described in the documentation.

It thus acts like a *vanilla* Django `ManyToManyField` when updating the relation with tags.